# How can I share data between glfw and the engine?

Tags: glfw

I am making a 2d custom engine
I want to know how to get input from glfw and then change this to the postion property of my engine. Global variables are one way, but I don't think this is a good way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything depends on the architecture of your engine.  Also if you are building it using a structural language like C or OOP with C++. I prefer you use OOP and collect the control variables for each class/object (the ones you want to control) then use the input to manipulate

To get inputs using glfw use glfwGetKey()